# How to import a module at each execution of python?

Tags: python

I need to run the command `import numpy as np` each time I run python. How to automatize it in linux. In other words, how do load a module each time python is launch with having to manually call it?

Answer (score 2):

The `-i` flag can help with that. See `man python`.

```
       -i     When  a  script  is  passed as first argument or the -c option is
              used, enter interactive mode after executing the  script  or  the
              command.   It does not read the $PYTHONSTARTUP file.  This can be
              useful to inspect global variables or a stack trace when a script
              raises an exception.
```

So the below does what you want it to. Note that the `-i` flag needs to precede the `-c` otherwise it doesn't work.

```
 python -i -c 'import numpy'
```

Comment: Actually a better way would be to create a file containing `import numpy as np` and assign its name to PYTHONSTARTUP - preferably in .bashrc or any other shell script that is executed by starting shell (depends on the shell being used).